# How can we pose a question on an alleged Bible contradiction without getting opinion based questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, opinion-based

I want to ask a few questions on alleged "Biblical Contradictions" and get answers to some of the ones that stump me to see if I can word my responses better.

My fear is that my question will be struck down as "opinion based", since clearing up an objection or contradiction may have different answers depending on who you ask, even if two different people hold the same worldview.

That being said, I don't want to do the thing that people normally do, which is asking a denominations opinion on a verse or asking for a denomination overview. That seems "cheaty" to me.

So how can I pose a question on how to clear up a biblical contradiction without being struck down for opinion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If one part of the Bible supports a doctrine and another part of the Bible seems to refute it, just ask "Why do people do X when the Bible clearly says to do Y".

   You can mention the contradiction in the meat of the question, but it's not the subject. tag [biblical-basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis)
2. If you're just asking about the text, ask on [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)
3. We do have a tag called [textual-discrepancies](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-discrepancies) they don't seem to get closed very often.  I, for one, am not going to go hunting them out to close, unless you put "Why did God..." in your title.

Comment: Yes, most "how can this contradiction be resolve?" questions belong on Hermeneutics, unless they're specifically targeted to one denomination.